# How to set Neo4j community edition as a reliable service?

Tags: neo4j

I have set up neo4j on EC2. Now I want to be able to access it from remote.
I want to it to be high-performance, for which seems I need to create cluster.

The neo4j documentation says that the clustering features are available in Neo4j Enterprise Edition.

I want to know that is there anything I can do with the community edition?

Comment: why do you think you need a cluster, so that you can access it remote ?

Comment: @TomažBratanič I can access it remote now. I think  clustering makes it high-performance.

Comment: @TomažBratanič edited the post :)

Answer (score 0):

Clustering, which is good for both "high performance" (load balancing) and fault tolerance, is not supported by the community edition.

That means that with the community edition you only have a single server available to handle the load and that you have a single point of failure. That does not mean that the community edition is necessarily "low performance", however, and many people are happy with it for pretty large DBs. It all depends on what you are trying to use it for.